# Sense amplifier in memory

Tags: digital-logic

What is the functioning of a sense amplifier?
Does it take 2 inputs and calculate which is higher or lower, then output a signal?

I have come across this in S RAM

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can you edit your question to give some context to it? Where did you come across the term? You have tagged it as "digital logic" but it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Why is your name transistor?

Comment: @user10713170 Because that's the name they set in their profile.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_basic_idea_behind_the_SRAM_sense_amplifier_Why_do_we_need_such_an_exotic_circuit_solution